# Finding out which image that have been clicked on using javascript/ jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-gallery

I'm making a kind of gallery and the purpose should be, that if you click on an image a larger one with display on the screen. With the image it should be a title and a text. My issue is, how can I found out which one that have been clicked on, so that the right image and the right text and title displays?

By using `this.src` I was able to found out the image source, but couldn't find a way to go from there. Don't know if thats being on the right track or not...

Anyway. here's my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var gallery = [
            {
                "img" : "img/gallery/gameboy2.png",
                "title" : "GameBoy Color",
                "about" : "A-ball",
                "price" : 99,
                "category" : ["gameboy", "color", "console", "game"]

            },
            {
                "img" : "img/gallery/phone.png",
                "title" : "Hamburger Phone",
                "about" : "What is a smartphone?",
                "price" : 129,
                "category" : ["phone","hamburger"]
            },
            {
                "img" : "img/gallery/gameboy.png",
                "title" : "Nintendo GameBoy",
                "about" : "Things doesnt get better with time. This is the shit.",
                "price" : 499,
                "category" : ["game","console", "gameboy"]
            },
            {
                "img" : "img/gallery/game2.png",
                "title" : "SEGA",
                "about" : "Things doesnt get better with time. This is the shit.",
                "price" : 699,
                "category" : ["game","console", "sega"]
            },
                        {
                "img" : "img/gallery/gameboy2.png",
                "title" : "GameBoy Color",
                "about" : "A-ball",
                "price" : 99,
                "category" : ["gameboy", "color", "console", "game"]

            },
            {
                "img" : "img/gallery/phone.png",
                "title" : "Hamburger Phone",
                "about" : "What is a smartphone?",
                "price" : 129,
                "category" : ["phone","hamburger"]
            },
            {
                "img" : "img/gallery/gameboy.png",
                "title" : "Nintendo GameBoy",
                "about" : "Things doesnt get better with time. This is the shit.",
                "price" : 499,
                "category" : ["game","console", "gameboy"]
            },
            {
                "img" : "img/gallery/game2.png",
                "title" : "SEGA",
                "about" : "Things doesnt get better with time. This is the shit.",
                "price" : 699,
                "category" : ["game","console", "sega"]
            }

];

var submit_search = document.getElementById("submit_search");
submit_search.addEventListener("click", searchItem);

showItemsList(gallery);


/*
    Create a li element and append to already existing ul
    Show an image of the product, and below the image show product title and price
*/

function showItemsList(gallery) {
    var ul = document.getElementById("product_list");
    ul.innerHTML = "";

    for(i =0; i < gallery.length; i++) {

        // get the current product
        var currentProduct = gallery[i];

        // create element li 
        var li = document.createElement('li');                           

        // create product img
        var productImg = document.createElement('img');
        productImg.src = currentProduct.img;
        productImg.className = "thumbnail";
        productImg.addEventListener("click", showItem);
        li.appendChild(productImg); 

        // create caption
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(currentProduct.title + " " + currentProduct.price + "kr"));                                         
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }

}

/*
    If someone click on a product, show a larger picture with a caption telling about the product
    If you click the picture again, it minimize back to a thumbnail

*/
function showItem() {

    // display the layer
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";

    // add the name of  the product
    var h2 = document.getElementById("header_products");
    var single_item_page = document.getElementById("single_item");
    h2.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Hej"));


}
```

Comment: When you add any element into a page, you can attach an "onClick" callback to that element.  The function mentioned in the onClick will be called when the item is clicked.  The event passed with onClick will identify which element was clicked.

Comment: I've used "addEventListener" instead of onClick, heard that its a better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('ul li').click(function(){

    var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    var keepGoing = true;

    $.each(gallery, function(index, obj){

        if (!keepGoing)
               return true;

        if (obj.img == src){

            alert(obj.title);
            keepGoing = false;
        }
    })
});
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/v4n4LdxL/1/

To avoid iterating through all of your images when one is clicked, you can sue the image src as the keys in the gallery variable.

Example:

```
$(function(){

    var gallery = {
         "img/gallery/gameboy2.png" : {
                "title" : "GameBoy Color",
                "about" : "A-ball",
                "price" : 99,
                "category" : ["gameboy", "color", "console", "game"]

            },
          "img/gallery/phone.png": {
                "title" : "Hamburger Phone",
                "about" : "What is a smartphone?",
                "price" : 129,
                "category" : ["phone","hamburger"]
            }
    };

    $('ul li').click(function(){

        var src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        var img = gallery[src];

        alert(img.title);

    });

});
```

Here's the fiddle for that approach:

http://jsfiddle.net/v4n4LdxL/2/

**Edit:** updated fiddle

Comment: So I just just add that under my array and not care about the function `showItem`?

Comment: You can replace the `alert` in the examples above with whatever functions you want to call when the event kicks off, including `showItem` :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but jQuery is still a bit hard for me.. ended up with adding an id on every img element and used `this.id` to get the right result.

Answer (score 0):

You can find index by using jQuery.

For example you can run this click function to send alert

```
$('ul li').click(function(){ alert($(this).index()); });
```